# Laravel Eloquent get many through other table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Hi I have three tables

**Recipes**

```
id | name
1  | Spaghetti
```

**Food**

```
id | name
1  | tomato
2  | banana
```

**Ingredient Recipes**

```
id | idRecipe | idFood
1  | 1         | 1
2  | 1         | 2
```

How to from Recipes I can get **all** name Food through table Ingredient Recipes?

In Model Recipes I try to use Eloquent relationship Has many through but it not work

```
public function NameFood()
  {
      return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Food', 'App\IngredientRecipes', 'idRecipe', 'id', 'idFood');
  }
```

Comment: read this https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: in my table "Ingredient Recipes" have 2 foreginkey

Comment: in that guide: Each user has only one country_id

Comment: **$names = $this->recipes->findOrFail($recipe_id)->NameFood;** should cover it?

Comment: Dan White: Put to where?

Answer (score 1):

In your Recipe model u can create a belongsToMany relation.

```
class Recipe extends Model
{
    public function foods()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            App\Food::class,
            'ingredient_recipes',
            'idRecipe',
            'idFood',
        );
    }
}
```

Now u can take all foods from Recipe by:

```
$all_foods = $my_recipe->foods;
$only_names = $my_recipe->foods->pluck('name');
```

Better call your foreign keys like: "tablename_id" example: "food_id", "recipe_id". It's auto naming in laravel relations.

I hope it's okay answer for you. :) Good luck.